# ES6 equivalent code for shorthand object creation with empty check

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

i am able to assign null to a key if key value is empty as follows

```
var object = {testKey:testKey || null}
```

but using es6 shorthand object creation method i am not able to write as

```
const object = {testKey}
```

but not

`const object = {testKey || null}`
what is the equivalent es6 code for this

```
var object = {testKey:testKey || null}
```

Comment: `const object = {testKey: testKey ? testKey : null}`

Comment: @hillmark, this is indeed the way to do it, but it can't be considered as an "ES6 shorthand", (it's just  ES5)...

Comment: Even in `var object = {testKey:testKey || null}` the variable `testKey` is defined (atleast having a value of `null`). So if testKey is defined, then you can do `const object = {testKey}`. It would evaluate to `{testKey: null}` or `{testKey: "somevalue"}` depending on the value of `testKey`.

Comment: Yes, it works okay if testKey is assigned `let testKey = null`, as opposed to simply declared `let testKey`, but still not quite what the OP has in mind by the looks of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking whether there is any special syntax for doing this check: there isn't.

```
var object = {testKey: testKey || null}
```

is the most concise you can get (ignoring renaming variables).

If you want to avoid repeating the variable name (I can see that there are valid reasons for this, but e.g. strict mode would adequately protect you against typos), then you could update the variable before using it as a property:

```
testKey = testKey || null;
var object = {testKey};
```

Of course that changes the value of `testKey` so it's not equivalent to the first code.